# Lower bound for finding kth smallest element using adversary arguments

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

In many texts a lower bound for finding $k$th smallest element is derived making use of arguments using medians. How can I find one using an adversary argument?

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) says that tournament algorithm runs in $O(n+k\log n)$, and $n - k + \sum_{j = n+2-k}^{n} \lceil{\operatorname{lg}\, j}\rceil$ is [given](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Lower_bounds) as lower bound.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am going to briefly outline a sketch of an adversary argument.

Consider your selection algorithm playing against an opponent that we will call the adversary.The aim of the adversary is to provide an input $X$ for your algorithm that maximizes the number of comparison operations done by your algorithm. Indeed, your algorithm can be seen as a comparison tree, in which a path corresponds to a partial order. When the algorithm asks the adversary about a pair $(x, y)$ of elements, the adversary returns either $x < y$ or $y < x$. The adversary answers can never contradict previous outcomes.

Assume that the $k$-th largest element is $x^*$: considering the partial order associated to any leaf of the comparison tree, then $x^*$ must be comparable with every other element in order for the algorithm to be correct, so that the algorithm must have made at least one comparison $(y, z)$ $\forall y \neq x^*$ whose outcome is either $y < z \leq x^*$ or $x^* \leq z < y$. Call such a comparison *crucial* for an element $y$. Obviously, the adversary wants to maximize the number of non crucial comparisons done by your algorithm.

Let $L$ be the set of $k−1$ largest elements; your algorithm needs to correctly identify all of the elements in $L$ and also the largest element in $X \setminus L$, i.e. $x^*$. Observe that each element in $X \setminus L$ has lost at least one crucial comparison. Now, the adversary has a strategy that forces each of the $k - 1$ elements in $L$ to win at least $\left\lceil {\lg \frac{n}{{k - 1}}} \right\rceil$ comparisons, none of which is crucial for $X \setminus L$. Adding the remaining $n - k$ crucial comparisons for $X \setminus L$ you obtain the lower bound. For details, please read the following, excellent, Jeff Erikson [notes](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/497/02-selection.pdf).

Comment: @JeffE I am confused about the definition of `crucial comparison for $y$`: the comparisons $y : z$ where either $y < z \le x^{\ast}$ or $x^{\ast} \le z < y$ and $x^{\ast}$ is the target element. What if we don't know the relation between $z$ and $x^{\ast}$ when these comparisons are made? Do we have an _oracle_ here? Or are we omniscient with full information (even the future information in the leaf)?